# DateTime.TryParse() not working with formatted date dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#

This code returns (min time 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM) not Date.Time.Now . Try Parse works for MM/dd/yyyy but not dd/MM/yyyy . Any suggestions

Here is code

```cs
DateTime start, end;
DateTime.TryParse(EPSDate12.Text, out start);
string  TNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); // Works
//   string  TNow = DateTime.Now.ToString();// works but gives MM/dd/yyyy as expected 
DateTime.TryParse(TNow, out end); // No. gives min time (1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM)
```

Comment: You could use [`TryPraseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What exactly is your input text? Can you put that in as valid C# code?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1179/ for the win. If you for some reason have to use some other format (why?) instead of default for your locale indeed you must use TryParseExact with exactly the same format as used for ToString call.

Comment: So you should parse using an overload where a `CultureInfo` is an expected arg. And that culture should support "dd/MM/yyyy" as dt format. TryParse without an `IFormatProvider` (usually a CultureInfo) specified uses the current culture (of the executing thread). And in your case current culture doesnt seem to support DMY but rather MDY (likely en-us)...

Answer (score 2):

Use [TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-5.0) and supply the format string.

Also examine the return value from TryParseExact to know if it failed or not (it returns a bool)

I see "EPSDate12.Text" which i suspect may be a TextBox: If you're doing this in a UI, make life easy and use a DateTimePicker - you can set the format, the user can type into them just like a textbox, but they don't accept invalid inputs, and all you have to do is get the `.Value` property which gives you a DateTime

---

As to why your attempts to parse the string you made don't work, I think it most likely that the date format Parse is using (which is based on the culture settings of the executing thread) is not the same format as the string you prepared using your forced format. Either make sure your forced format is matched to the current culture, or use a culture that matches your forced format, or use [Try]ParseExact to force the format for parsing like you did when creating the string

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=net-5.0#Culture for more info

Comment: This is helpful, but it doesn't answer the OP's question as to why `DateTime.TryParse` is not working. However, it's probably because the input string doesn't match the pattern.

Comment: I have added a paragraph to address your concern

Comment: Thanks for suggestions . Yes DateTime.TryParse is not working and it could be format issue This line of code. string  TNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"); generates for TNow  29/07/2021 14:49:03 . which looks OK but fails TryParse

Comment: What would you like me to do with that information?

Answer (score 0):

The datetime value is internally the same. But, ToString() return value, depends on
the local machine culture setup.

[Reference article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-5.0#formatting-01)

> The default DateTime.ToString() method returns the string
> representation of a date and time value using the current culture's
> short date and long time pattern. The following example uses the
> default DateTime.ToString() method.

For en-US culture(`MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`) , it will be in

> 7/28/2021 11:37:40 AM

If you want to see in en-GB(`dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss`), you can apply conversion as given below:

```cs
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
MessageBox.Show($"{DateTime.Now.ToString(culture)}");
```

> 28/07/2021 11:45:09 AM

you can also specify exact custom format, in which you want to display.

```cs
MessageBox.Show($"{DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt")}");
```

> 28/07/2021 11:45:09 AM

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestions . Yes DateTime.TryParse is not working and it could be format issue
This line of code.
string TNow = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

generates
29/07/2021 14:49:03
which looks OK but fails TryParse